# Is the scalar curvature of the Schwarzschild solution 0?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, curvature

The Schwarzschild solution is meant to be a solution of the vacuum Einstein equations. That is

$$R_{\mu\nu}=0.$$

So, the Ricci tensor must be null for $r>0$.

Now, if the scalar curvature is nothing but the Ricci tensor contracted, and the Ricci tensor is null, the cuvature should be zero.

Nonetheless, I have been told that the curvature of the Schwarzschild solution (in the usual coordinates) is

$$\frac{12r_s^2}{r^6},$$

which is obviously non zero.

What am I making wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're correct that $R=0$. $R_{abcd} R^{abcd} = \frac{12 r_s^2}{r^6}$ is the [Kretschmann scalar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kretschmann_scalar) for the Schwarzschild metric, an invariant used to find the true singularities of a spacetime. In this case, only the singularity at $r=0$ is a spacetime singularity, not a coordinate-system one.