# Dirac Delta Function and Schwarzschild Singularity

Tags: general-relativity, curvature, gravitational-waves, singularities, dirac-delta-distributions

Pardon my naive question. I recently found out about Dirac Delta function. It is interesting to note that Schwarzschild singularity gives the infinity values of the General relativity field equations for single/multiple objects object. Now are there any relation between both? Is is possible to assume that the parameterized Mathematical Functions(s) of Gravitational waves emanated from a set of physical objects - if you take the limit of that parameterized function - that it is a Dirac Delta function or a variant where in the value at $x=a$ is $\infty$? If it is then we try modelling the Schwarzschild singularity and working backwards to  ...correct? or am I completely off-track?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ricci scalar for Black Hole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/269202/)

Comment: Do you mean is it scalar infinities? Then yes, I did mean scalar infinities that are co-ordinate system invariant on non-regular points.  Or do you mean like Transfinite numbers like order of $\mathbb{N}$ being different from $\mathbb{R}$?