# For the Schwarzschild metric, are the values of the Ricci tensor and Ricci scalars always zero?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, curvature, vacuum

If we use the Schwarzschild metric to solve the [Einstein field equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations), would the values of the Ricci tensor and scalars always be zero?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the scalar curvature of the Schwarzschild solution 0?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/118671/)

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

It follows straight from the

$$ R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu} = 8\pi T_{\mu\nu}$$

If there's no matter sources (spacetime outside the event horizon), $T_{\mu\nu}=0$.

We're left with:

$$ R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu} = 0$$

If you contract with $g^{\mu\nu}$ on both sides, you're getting:

$$ R- \frac{1}{2}R \cdot 4 = - R = 0$$

And therefore the Ricci scalar vanishes identically.

Plugging this into the vacuum field equation:

$$ R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu} = R_{\mu\nu} = 0$$

we see that the Ricci tensor vanishes identically as well.

To add more flavour to this answer, as this might seem counter-intuitive, the Ricci curvature tensor is not the only part of the spacetime curvature, but the one that gets coupled directly to the matter sources.

The full curvature of a spacetime is described by the Riemann curvature tensor, which in vacuum case reduces to the so-called Weyl tensor. Weyl tensor describes the part of the gravitational curvature which is not in the immediate vicinity of the sources.

So in a BH spacetime, $R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} \neq 0$.

If we want to have a scalar description of the spacetime curvature present in such spacetimes, we can use the Kretschmann scalar:

$$ K = R_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}R^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}$$

which in Schwarzschild is:

$$K = \frac{48 M^{2}}{r^{6}} $$

Comment: Interestingly, this reasoning fails in $2$-dimensional spacetime because the Einstein tensor is then traceless.

Comment: @J.G. In 2d the Einstein tensor is not only traceless but simply vanishes.

Comment: @OON Harder to prove, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only if you ignore dark energy. Considering dark energy, the field equations are given by:
\begin{equation}
R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{R}{2}g_{\mu\nu}+\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}
=\kappa T_{\mu\nu}.
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}
Contracting with the inverse metric tensor $g^{\mu\nu}$ results in:
\begin{equation}
\underbrace{g^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu}}_{=R}
-\frac{R}{2}\underbrace{g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu}}_{=4}
+\Lambda\underbrace{g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu}}_{=4}
=\kappa\underbrace{g^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}}_{=T}
\Rightarrow
-R+4\Lambda=\kappa T
\Rightarrow
R=4\Lambda-\kappa T.
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation}
In a vacuum, we have $T=0$ and therefore $R=4\Lambda$, which does not vanish for $\Lambda\neq 0$. In a vacuum, we even have $T_{\mu\nu}=0$. Putting equation (2) (with $T=0$) in equation (1) (with $T_{\mu\nu}=0$), we get:
\begin{equation}
R_{\mu\nu}
=\frac{R}{2}g_{\mu\nu}-\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}
=\Lambda g_{\mu\nu},
\end{equation}
which also does not vanish for $\Lambda\neq 0$.

Comment: In the presence of dark energy the solution wouldn't be Schwarzschild, it would be the de Sitter–Schwarzschild metric, so I'm not sure introducing dark energy is appropriate.

Comment: I maybe should have written it already in my answer: I just wrote mine to give a generalization to the previous answer (which fully answers the question asked) since introducing dark energy changes it.